# UWP Equivalent of .NET UIElement.TranslatePoint

Tags: c#, uwp

I am looking to get the position of a UIElement relative to it's container to overlay an image on top of it.

UIElement in the System.WIndows namespace has exactly what I want.
What is the equivalent in UWP ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [UIElement.TransformToVisual(UIElement)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual) Method.

If you wanted the top-left point, here's what's the code could look like:

```
var top_left = child_uiElement.TransformToVisual(container_uiElement).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0,0));
```

Comment: I am having a strange problem. The child_uiElement is found by using VisualTreeHelp to traverse to an Image in the row of a ListView in my RelativePanel. Sometimes the resulting point is valid. If the list contents are changed ... and I still traverse the VisualTree to find the new child_uiElelent. In this case the resulting  point has large negative x and y values. It's like TransformToVisual has problems when the child is embeded in a ListView in the parent. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that

Comment: Tracked the problem to VisualTreeHelper ... when I collapsed the List from 3 items to 2 items, the VisualTreeHelper still found a 3rd row with no usable data .. and I was just looking for the last item ... What a kludge to fix this .. I had to stop looking when I found the number of items that were in the list ... I guess the class should have been  called MostlyVisualTreeHelper

Comment: Hi @r.t.s. This should be another issue, please open a new thread with details to clarify it.