# Again, PointToScreen in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I found a winforms open source G-code Back-Plotter and I'd like to convert part of it to UWP before adding to it.
https://github.com/nm156/CNCInfusion --- (for the original code)

As a hobbiest, I have quite a bit of experiance with C# and Winforms, less with WPF, and none with UWP.

In short, I have this one line that is killing me, I've converted everything else...

p1 = PointToScreen(p1);

One item that is important to note here is that this line comes from a Winforms User Control.

It seems the documentation is telling me I need to use TransformPoint, which is referenced in Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.dll, but this is a no-go (and obviously, I'm wrong on multiple points).

In Intellesence drop-down menus, TransformPoint does not exist. The 'using' declaration is there along with the reference. I can see all the other methods exposed, just not the one I'm looking to experiment with.

Furthermore, I've been searching online with the tags "UWP" and ".Net Core". Obviously my google-foo needs improvement. Really seems UWP documentation is lacking or I'm just not looking in the right places.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To add, "p1" is a POINT struct; This struct lives in the Nuget System.Drawing.Primitives assembly for UWP

Comment: What is the objective of `PointToScreen` method?

Comment: screen drawing/ placement... not sure what else you could be asking....

Comment: are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618257/uwp-equivalent-of-net-uielement-translatepoint/50621819#50621819

Comment: private void DrawWinMouseRect(Point p1, Point p2) is what feeds the p1 = PointToScreen(p1); problem... I would like to make the port as close as possible. That solution breaks in multiple ways, one being Windows.Foundation.Point is the data type returned which conflicts with the POINT data struct. I don't want to try casting at this point.

Comment: I've had to rename one variable, but no longer getting and 'red' on the screen by doing this.... Will not know if this works until I step through it...

Comment: Windows.Foundation.Point p3 = this.TransformToVisual(this).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(p1.X, p1.Y));

Comment: Been banging head against wall, numbing it with beer... Perhaps this will lead me somewhere... or not.

Comment: Muzib, I want to thank you graciously for your time and effort. I apologize for not supplying all needed info., after working for over 36 hours (no sleep), and a few beers, I shouldn't of bugged the community over this stupid problem. I'm to tired to debug or step though code now. Hopefully your link and my mods will work. Take care.

Comment: Hey, I haven't used WPF, so I don't know what does `PointToScreen` method does. So, I tried to guess what you needed. I'd really like to help you, If you want.

Comment: It doesn't matter because even if you get `PointToScreen` to work, the only thing it is used for is to call `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame`, which is not available in UWP. UWP does not let apps draw outside their window.