# How to get the rotated bounds of rectangle in uwp using Matrix values

Tags: c#, uwp

I have rotated a rectangle based using Transform Group in UWP. Once after rotation I need to get the new bounds of rectangle using the transform . Can anyone help me out on this

```
RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();
rotate.Angle = -angle;    
var translate = new TranslateTransform
{
X = offset,
Y = offset                                   
 };                                       
var group = new TransformGroup
{
 Children = { (Transform)translate.Inverse, rotate,translate }
};
rect.RenderTransform = group;
```

Comment: `newBoundsRect = group.TransformBounds(rect)`

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen, the snippet just returns the offset values. Is there any way to get the bounds or is it possible to get it using this values?

Comment: If you can access the `Parent` of the `Rectangle`, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618257/uwp-equivalent-of-net-uielement-translatepoint/50621819#50621819

Comment: Oh, I see, when you say "rotated a rectangle" you mean "rotated a `Rectangle` element, not a `Rect` structure. Once you figure out what coordinate system you want to get the result in, you can use `TransformToVisual` to get the coordinates of the `Rectangle`, apply the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` to get the dimensions as a `Rect`, and then apply the `RenderTransform` to the `Rect`.

Comment: var matrix = (rect.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Value;    Using this matrix and rectangle parameters, whether it is possible to get the new bounds of rectangle?